# Access denied when copying files to server (windows service VS console application)

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application, access-denied

I'm looking for explanation why when I want to copy files from **local** directory to **server** directory it works when I do it in **console application** but when I make an **windows service** it doesn't.

- I'm running both application and service on same computer with same logged user who has access to the server
- In the **ServiceProcessInstaller** I use `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem` but I tried also the NetworkService and LocalService, with the same result
- I start the service manually from the Services window(having `ServiceStartMode.Manual` set) but even if I set it on Automatic there is no change

It's possible that I'm missing some information, but I've been searching for quite while and really didn't find an explanation.

---

**Updated question:**
Why is it impossible to install service(with having `ServiceAccount.User` set) using the account of user who is installing it without asking him for username and password?

Comment: If it's running as a service it doesn't matter whether there even is a user logged on locally. It either connects to the other machine anonymously or using the *computer's* account - what permissions does the *computer's* account have on the remote location? (To use the computer's account rather than being anonymous, choose "Network Service")

Comment: Run your service under a dedicated account having the proper rights to access your share.

Comment: For some reason I expected it to have the same access as the user who is currently logged in, my bad.

Comment: Windows supports multiple user sessions being logged on at the same time.

Comment: Yeah but there is only one user who is installing the service so why can't it take his credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

Change serivce logon  for that windows service, restart and then try.

Refer to this blog -- http://jonathanmalek.com/2007/12/31/shortcut-setting-log-on-credentials-for-windows-services/